# need a little help from someone who understand code

Tags: python, function, file

```
import random

def main():
    random1 = random.randrange(10,21,1)
    create_file(random1)
    process_file()

def create_file( random1):
    generate = open('random_numbers.txt','w')
    for x in range(random1):
        random2 = random.randrange(1,101,1)
        generate.write(str(random2)+'/n')
    generate.close()

def process_file():
    generate = open('random_numbers.txt','r')
    entries = 0
    total = 0
    for x in generate:
        entries += 1
        integer = int(x)
        total = integer + total
        mean= sum/entries
    print("There are",(entries),"entries in the file.")
    print("The sum total of all the entries is ",(total))
    print("The average of all the entries is ", format((mean),'.2f'))
main()
```

This keeps giving me this error and ive don't understand why the integer value is not working.  I tried to reduce the `integer=int(x)` to `integer = x` but then I couldn't use the x as an integer and that's a problem in it of itself

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\john oconnor lab 6.2.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "U:\john oconnor lab 6.2.py", line 20, in main
    process_file()
  File "U:\john oconnor lab 6.2.py", line 35, in process_file
    number = int(x)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '29/n59/n17/n2/n8/n14/n2/n14/n9/n21/n5/n25/n15/n47/n'
```

Comment: So add back in the call to `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
generate.write(str(random2)+'/n')
```

Are you trying to write a newline at the end there? You got the escape sequence wrong.

```
generate.write(str(random2)+'\n')
```

This ought to fix the problem in `process_file`, since "random_numbers.txt" will now be filled with digits separated on their own individual lines, rather than being digits separated by a slash and the letter N.

---

Also, this line:

```
mean= sum/entries
```

Should use the variable `total` instead of the built-in function `sum`.

```
mean= total/entries
```

Comment: god dammit, I really would make a dumb mistake like that. Thanks for the help man, even if it was very simple

Answer (score 0):

When you do this `for x in generate:` your are getting every line of your file. So, as you know, every line of your file is something like '15\n' or '67\n'.

You should do this:

```
for x in generate:
    entries += 1
    x = x.strip()
    integer = int(x)
    total = integer + total
    mean= sum/entries
```

`x.strip()` will eliminate the term '\n' of every line.

Also be careful with the difference between '\n' and '/n'

Comment: `int` ignores leading and trailing whitespace, so `.strip()` would have no effect.  The real problem is the `/n`.